# Asking to reopen a question (How to support a friend with an insignificant problem)

Tags: discussion

Saw this question closed as too broad:

[How to support a friend with an 'insignificant' problem?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/6127/how-to-support-a-friend-with-an-insignificant-problem)

I'm recommending that it be reopened, because the last line of the post is a specific question:

> How can I change my handling of these interactions to become a better person and be a better support towards others?

One might argue that the first part is a touch broad still, but given context from the (long!) preamble, the guy is trying to reconcile a desire to be more supportive with his evident pride in his stoic beliefs.

The second part is clearly asking *how* to offer support, as he's not experienced at it.

Both halves of the question seem answerable.  At least enough that concerned answer-givers can take a whack at it.

Comment: It's been reopened, but it really should be condensed.

Answer (score 2):

I put some effort into editing that question.

However, I still think it should remain on-hold for now:

- I haven't seen the OP around after the last edit. This edit was quite significant. I asked the OP to confirm if I did understand correctly, and I still haven't got an answer to that.
- There was a close-vote cast after my editing. I collected some feedback in chat, and it basically boils down to "We want a real-life example so we can tell whether you're being dramatic or not".

As it is, it's very borderline. Yes, it might be answerable in more general terms. I thought at first that the edit was good enough as well, and was somewhat surprised by the last close-vote.

But, 
[see this comment](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/6127/how-to-support-a-friend-with-an-insignificant-problem#comment23606_6127). It's one of the first, and it's basically asking for more real-life examples. My edit didn't add those. Although I do think I let this comment weigh in with my close-vote. So, I'm not confident voting to reopen it without those details being added.

I'll leave one last nudge for the OP and a link to the meta question there, hopefully we can improve it enough so I can feel free to reopen it as well

Comment: Thanks for the edit Tinker, the edit is done well. I haven't been around because I'm in an eastern time zone (currently 9:40 AM).

While the second half of the question is how to give better support, the first half is also something interesting- how to change so that I don't lose respect / despise / am jealous of those who come to me for support.

Comment: "How can I change my handling of these interactions to become a better person and be a better support towards others?"
Also the question is a bit misleading, I do offer good support and my handling of these situations is fine, I don't get called out for giving bad support, but I feel that I'm being fake, and I begin resenting the person who requesting the support. So the question is more of a 'how to change how I feel / perceive the other person' in this scenario.

Comment: @InterP I'm sorry for the 'misleading'. But we can't change you, your feelings or perceptions... It's up to you to provide the examples that were asked for, or wait a while longer to see if the 5th reopen vote will be cast as well, without answering the comments...You might want to edit in 'I don't get called out for bad support, but feel like I'm being fake' into there yourself (pro-tip: Just edit it into the main body, not a separate paragrhap called with 'edit' ;) )

Comment: Updated with examples

Comment: While there may be some merit to address the OP's situation specifically (re: the conversation you had in chat), I believe that answers to this question would be more useful to future visitors if it dealt with the general premise (as the top-voted answers indeed do) instead of getting bogged down in whether the exact situation of the OP is valid. See this post on academia.se's meta for a similar-ish discussion there. https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/834/people-denying-the-situation-in-the-questions-instead-of-answering